# jQuery overscroll plugin Android compatibility

Tags: jquery, overscroll

I'm currently implementing Overscroll plugin within the jQuery application. However, it is not quite compatible on Android platform and continuously resets it's x-axis whenever I click on the element that has Overscroll plugin applied. 
Here is an example code on JSFiddle.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(".overscrolled").overscroll();   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nsoefjrn/

Thank you.

Comment: Sidenote - `window` doesn't have a `ready` event, only `document`. Happens to work because it's ignored.

Comment: Thanks. It might be ignored, instead jQuery applies it to document.

Comment: Looks like it's only meant for desktop... why not detect touch and switch to momentum scrolling?